# The number of terms in the expansion of a binomial

Tags: binomial-theorem

If I have a binomial raised to the power n i.e $(a+b)^n$. Then the number of terms that its expansion yields will be $n+1$. This is very difficult for me to show(i.e How the number of terms are $n+1$). Any help will be appreciated. Tag is suggesgted.

Comment: Do you want a proof of the binomial theorem?

Comment: @JKnecht No I want to show how the number of terms in the expansion of that binomial are $n+1$

Comment: I dont understand. A proof of the binomial theorem shows why there are n + 1 terms in the expansion.

Comment: How many terms does a sum like $\sum_{k=0}^n c_k$ contain?

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo Surely $n+1$

Comment: So what else do you need? $(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n c_k$, where $c_k={n\choose k}a^k b^{n-k}$ (by the binomial theorem).

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo  OK fine.

Comment: You could draw a Pascal's triangle, if that helps "show" anything (not entirely clear what kind of intuitive clarification you're looking for).

Answer (score 3):

You want to find the number of distinct terms of the form $a^kb^{n-k}$. Once you have picked a $k$, the exponent $n-k$ is set. For different $k_1$ and $k_2$, the terms $a^{k_1}$ and $a^{k_2}$ are different, so each $k$ defines a unique monomial. Since you can choose $k$ between $0$ and $n$, there are $n-0+1$ terms.

This is a direct approach. You can also prove that by induction.